# setting an advancedDataGrid row backgroundColor to a gradiant via myStyleFunction

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I want to change the background color of my row to a gradiant

So here is my advancedDataGrid;

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="statsGrid" width="100%" height="100%" styleFunction="myStyleFunc" />
```

Here is how I change a complete row fontWeight to "bold" and color to red if the string "ALL" is in any cell of that row.

```
private function myStyleFunc(data:Object,col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object {
                try {
                    if(data) {
                        for( var propertyName : * in data){
                            if (data[propertyName] == "ALL") { 
                                return {fontWeight:"bold",color :"#FF0000"};


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch(err:Error) {}
                return {fontWeight:"normal"};      
            }
```

Here is a piece of code I use in another segment of my code to make a button have a blue gradient.

```
<s:Rect radiusX="4" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#333333" ratio="0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="#666666" ratio="1" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
```

So my question is how do I use something similar to the S:Rect code in my myStyleFunc():Object to return a background color bgColor that is gradiant?

Comment: Can you create a gradient in Flex CSS?  If not, then you can't use styleFunction(); you'll have to use a custom renderer.

Comment: Ok, thanks Reboog711. I'll try doing it in CSS if not I will just use a solid color. Would you happen to know a link to a list of styles I can return via styleFunction?

Comment: If I understand the docs; then you can set any style via the styleFunction().  I've never used it in practice; in fact never heard of it until now.  Styling isn't my area of expertise. You may be able to create your background as a separate component and specify that component as the property of a background; but I'm not entirely sure.